# How to use ASCII Art symbols in Message Dialogs of Unicode-by-default Delphi XE Applications

Tags: delphi, dialog, ascii, delphi-xe, ascii-art

I have searched subject offers, but Did not manage to get right one ...

Sorry if I am mistaking. If so, please point to correct Question here.

Okay, back to business. Situation: I am using ShowMessage() as simple "Status Briefing" provider for some events in Application:

```
procedure SatusBriefingDialog();
begin
  if Sender = SomeObject then 
  begin
    Application.NormalizeToMosts;
    MessageDlg(Handle, PChar('The_string_that_forms_nice_informative_window / dialog'));
    Application.RestoreTopMosts;
  end;
end;
```

Now, I want to polish it, therefore I want to use [extended ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/), but, I cannot choose best way to access them. Maybe I just don't know that magical function ...

Here is approach that uses OEMToANSI / OEMToChar and vice-verse functions: http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Pascal/Delphi/Q_20381022.html . I tried them with no luck, probobly because of:

> Syntax from [EDN / MS-Help](http://ms-help://embarcadero.rs_xe/Winui/winui/windowsuserinterface/resources/strings/stringreference/stringfunctions/oemtochar.htm)
>
> BOOL OemToChar(          LPCSTR lpszSrc,
>       LPTSTR lpszDst
>   );
>
> Parameters
>
> lpszSrc [in] Pointer to a
>   null-terminated string of characters
>   from the OEM-defined character set.
>
> lpszDst [out] Pointer to the buffer
>   for the translated string.
>
> If the OemToChar function is being used as an
>   ANSI function, the string can be
>   translated in place by setting the
>   lpszDst parameter to the same address
>   as the lpszSrc parameter. ***This cannot
>   be done if OemToChar is being used as
>   a wide-character function.***

What I need is Char(Ord(170)); , Char(Ord(180)); and Char(Ord(190)) - http://www.asciitable.com/. Obviously, with default WInXP codepage I cannot use them. Now, I google a bit and found this solution:

---

FormShow Event Code:

```
procedure TMain.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
var
   i : longint;
begin
  re.Font.Name := 'Terminal';
  re.Font.Size := 9;
//seems that charset must be set last
  re.Font.Charset := OEM_CHARSET;
  re.DefAttributes.Name := 'Terminal';
  re.DefAttributes.Size := 9;
  re.DefAttributes.Charset := OEM_CHARSET;
  re.SelectAll;
  re.SelAttributes := re.DefAttributes;
//turn off richedit's auto font switching...
  i := SendMessage(re.Handle, EM_GETLANGOPTIONS, 0, 0);
  i := i and not IMF_AUTOFONT;
  SendMessage(re.Handle, EM_SETLANGOPTIONS, 0, i);
end;
```

Also these Fonts will display correctly >>
Courier New
Lucida Console
MS Mincho

---

Now, the question is - what would be best way to say Windows Dialogs (API) to use OEM charset withing procedure that triggers ShowMessage(); ? Overriding ShowMessage(); ? Inheriting some richedit features? Various OwnerDraw() or WndProc() approaches ... too many options, but ... which ... I am confused. :(

Help me to choose and point to, of course, subjectively most effective and most code-less solution.

Comment: I think you're just going to make your program look *worse*. This isn't DOS, where you needed to provide the entire UI yourself. The OS already provides a nice-looking window. You're also free to create your own custom windows; instead of the box-drawing characters, put a TPanel or a TShape on a form to draw an *actual* box. Or, if you just want something that's a little more than a plain message box, use a [*task dialog*](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/atbdev5.asp).

Comment: The thing is specific ( for me and my goals I have set for this app I develop ) - I try to write at least partially compatible app with current WineHQ devel snapshot, so I want to avoid OwnerDraw and various ShowMessage deriving / overloading / overrinding / inheriting techniques. If I would decide to put any of those VCLs into ShowMessage or MessageBox, it includes Windows Handle manipulations, which are not jet stable under WIneHQ environment. Even URL AutoDetection do not work until now ... so what to expect for such internal functionality intrusion ... ? ;)

Comment: @HX_unbanned: A form with a panel and a shape *should work*. If you can't use *that*, why exactly are you using Delphi?

Comment: I can. But I don't want to debug it and in worst case - code workaround, if issues occur. I am driving whole project by myself, in same time studying and working for living, also translating ubuntu ... and private life ... it would be just too much ... And, I use delphi because it can do what I want and how I want. I am not ASM coder, but I want to go in-depth when I want, so C-type langs at some point are overkill.

Comment: @HX_unbanned: If you can't use a simple form with a panel and a shape, you can't use the VCL. If you don't use the VCL all that's left is the compiler. If all you use is the compiler, you might as well use FPC. If you insist on doing cross-platform work use a true corss-platform tool: Python and Java come to mind. Even .NET might be a workable choice. Kylix is also interesting if you can lay your hands on it. I'm trying to suggest that maybe you're going on the wrong path...

Comment: Maybe. Nice input for thinking and choice for future, Cosmin. Thank you ;)

Comment: @HX_unbanned If you are happy to use Wine then you can use the entire VCL with confidence. Wine has been capable of running Delphi apps for many many years now.

Comment: Yes and No. It is discussable statement, David ;) In the context of Wine, "Capability of running something" is very general stand ... ;)

Comment: @HX_unbanned What are you talking about? I can run my 600,000 LOC Delphi app happily through WINE. It uses a wide selection of VCL controls, comctl32 controls, express spreadsheet, TeeChart, Direct 3D. Can you give me an example of a Delphi app that doesn't run on Wine?

Comment: David, now, LOC is not worth anything. It can either bee 600000 lines of WriteLn() and it will work w/o doubts, but once you include activex, odbc, encryption, WM, shell controls and other technologies, you will find out  what Wine can actually run ;) All you counted is pretty basic implementations and MOSTLY do not require OS wide DLL utilization .. Please, get more informed about Wines current devel and than we can talk more about this topic. Now you simple have got insufficient knowledge ;)

Comment: @HX_unbanned You are aware, I presume, that Wine runs MS Office. You want to draw some lines on a form and think Wine won't be able do do it? Really? You count Wine's ability to support D3D as basic? You believe that Wine can't cope with a Delphi TPanel and suggest that you are the knowledgeable one. In a comment you scold @mghie for being aggressive (he wasn't being so) but you are happy to insult me - perhaps you should take some of your own advice.

Comment: No, Sorry, but you forgot some things about bot MS Office and D3D. MS Office support has been independently and with focus - added, as Wines goal for some time was to support Adobe Photoshop CSx Suites ;) In the terms of D3D - It is obvious that Microsofts DirectX SDK provides great support and it would extremely weird if it would not support D3D ;) AND - still, I might be wrong, but there should be some bunch of functions still passed through OpenGL ... and after some time through OpenCL as Ubuntu ( for example ), supports Built-in OpenCL lib.

Comment: I am not insulting you. There is big diff between pointing out areas where you are wrong and actual insult, which is aimed to you as personality. I have no harm or wish to humiliate / insult anybody. We are talking here about GENERIC multi-tier, custom-solution software. MS Office simply cannot use implementations that widely differs from internal OS structure. Peace, college ;)

Comment: And - if it is GENERICS, that errors, that might occur, 99% times would be caused by some unknown or untraced issue. This is what I am afraid of. For example, some unimplemented / obselete GDI function that has not been implemented or is implemented, but suffers unknown bug, so things like Alpha channels would be buggy ( in fact they are now, but M$ do not care anymore ).

Comment: @HX_unbanned You seem to be moving away from the original point. You asserted that Wine will not be able to support a Delphi app using basic VCL features such as TPanel. In this assertion you are wrong. You are disparaging of Wine and so you propose to get around that by, er, using Wine!

Comment: Yeah, pardon. Anyway, I am not claiming Wine will not be able to support them. I am afraid that there are and I could hit some underwater stones within the VCLs and Custom Forms in current Wine version. AND - I am not getting around it by using Wine. You understood me in wrong way. W9ine compatibility is to enable some compatibility with other platforms. That's it.

Comment: @HX You have, at best, only a partial understanding of your work. This is in itself is not a problem – your problem is your tendency to attribute blame on others (WINE, Delphi etc.) when in fact the errors and misunderstandings are yours. This is all perfectly clear from your writings on Stack Overflow. You have asked a number of questions here and received much excellent advice (from kind people with much experience and knowledge). You would do well to heed more of this advice! Lecture over!  :-)

Comment: Thanks. I will keep in mind it :-) Free lectures is good thing in all situations ... but I am not student - I just try to explain reason why you are wrong in the terms to use TPanel or TShape or any other. You seems to ignore me and still claim that Wine can do anything, which is totally wrong. I appreciate and value each and every answer here, but your arguments unexceptionally are invalid here. Also, there is no such thing as "tendency to blame" anybody - there is just wish to understand in which area I am doing wrong. You got to read more carefully next time. Period. EOF();

Answer (score 7):

IF you're using a UNICODE version of Delphi, stop thinking about ASCII art in terms of ASCII chars. Every single one of those box-drawing chars has an UNICODE code point. Your Delphi's editor is perfectly capable of working with the codes directly, you can safely use them in your pascal source files.

Here's an example:

```
procedure TForm20.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage(
     '┌─────────────────────────────────────────────┐'#13#10 +
     '│ You have UNICODE DELPHI, you may now write  │'#13#10 +
     '│ this without any problems. Just copy-paste  │'#13#10 +
     '│ the chars you need from the wikipedia page. │'#13#10 +
     '└─────────────────────────────────────────────┘'
  );
end;
```

How did I write that? VERY easy: Open up this page [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_characters#Unicode) and copy-paste the box drawing characters that you need. That's right, you copy paste the actual char (the right-angled lines, the horizontal lines, the vertical lines, whatever you need) - you don't need to care about the Unicode code points themselves.

Now of course, making those characters properly show up the display is a different matter: You need an fixed-point font to do that. AFAIK you can't get an fixed-font point with `ShowMessage`, you'll need to write your own version of `ShowMessage`...

Comment: Wow, hmm ... seems like I have to move forward from low-level symbol displaying approach. Cannot believe,, but does it really mean that 21st Century is finally here?!

Comment: Okay. Result is pretty interesting as I am not symbol displaying guru. When I open Wiki page from my Ubuntu PC, all symbols are show correctly. When I open WIki page from my VirtualBoxed WinXP SP3 IE8, only single-line and double-line box drawing symbols are shown. When I copy the symbools with Copy and Paste into IDE, again "unknown symbols" characters - rectangles - are shown. Now gonna exec app in native Windows XP and W7 environment to see if it is just problem with font support in VirtualBox 4.0 for Ubuntu 10.10 .. NOTE: I code in Ubuntu under VirtualBoxed WInXP SP3 ...

Comment: The virtualization layer is supposed to be invisible: For the current matter you're running Windows XP SP3, and it should do well. I'm not big on HTML, but did you try an other browser? I'm using Opera and I can see all the usual Unicde chars just fine. Are you using default fonts? You still need an font that's capable of displaying the chars you want displayed. The defaults work well for me, can't tell about the alternatives.

Comment: I just opened the wikipedia page using IE, all characters look fine. Copy-pasting into the IDE also works fine. Check your fonts, check your customizations.

Comment: Hmm, interesting... Anyway - just ran app through network on other WinXP SP3 PC - still, rectangles are shown, not the symbols needed. Weird.

Comment: I've copy-pasted the boxes from the box-drawing wikipedia page into notepad, saved to file. This is the file: http://fisiere.sediu.ro/altele/unicode.txt for me it looks ok on Windows 2008 (opera and IE), Windows 7 (opera) and Windows XP (IE). Does it look OK to you?

Comment: No, it doesn't :( Rectangles are shown for +254x ; 257x, few correctly displayed symbols in +250x .. +253x, and only range that displays symbols correctly are +255x and +256x ... :( in Virtual WinXP. In Ubuntu ( FF 3.6.12 ), everything is displayed correctly.

Comment: If those simple Unicode chars don't show up you'll need to fix your Windows before you do anything else.

Comment: "does it really mean that 21st Century is finally here?" - we haven't been using OEM charset since 1995 or so, here in the real world!

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly then you want to use some of the box drawing characters, which are in the [Unicode range `2500-257F`](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2500.pdf). So you just need to show a message with Unicode text. If you are on Delphi 2009 or later it's very simple, you just insert the characters into your string:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  s: string;
begin
  s := 'Test ' + #$2523;
  MessageBox(Handle, PChar(s), nil, MB_OK);
end;
```

Even if you were on an earlier version of Delphi you could still call the Unicode variant of for example the [`MessageBox()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function, by using `MessageBoxW()` and passing it a `WideString`.

Comment: Sorry, mghie, correct symbol is not shown. Trued Both MessageBoxW(); ... PWideChar() param ... and WideString declaration ... :( Instead default "unknown" char - Rectangle - is shown. Also, I am passing string as parameter, not as variable.

Comment: +1. We're in Delphi XE, so we may as well use the Unicode characters directly instead of trying to get to them via two levels of code-page conversion. In either case, you'll still rely on the message-box font to include the box characters and for the widths of those characters to work well with the width of the enclosed text; good ASCII art requires knowing the dimensions of the characters.

Comment: @HX_unbanned: If the font doesn't contain the glyph you want displayed, then no amount of coding will help you get around that. I don't think you should try to use these box characters at all, Rob already wrote a perfect comment on your question why that is.

Comment: I know, I know, just it is always interesting what metamorphoisis of binary char representations happens "under the hood" .. in the world that people usually do not think about. I already feel like idiot ... please don't be so aggressive .. ;)